# What factors should be considered when installing packages manually?

Tags: installation, package-management

I have seen many packages' `readme` or `install` files on instructing how to install a package manually. But many times the results are erroneous.

They instruct us to do many thing with for example the `configure` file.

But many, many factors are involved in this procedure (dependencies, make, path variables and much more).

I am yet able to install a single package manually.

What are the common factors that should be considered with manual installations?

Comment: By manual install do you mean installing from source or installing packages through `dpkg`?

Comment: Using sources or binaries... But not through dpkg or any installer program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am answering this question under my knowledge .

you have to install build-essential to compile any package manually .

```
     sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Then you can configure your package with `./configure` 
   Then `make` and `sudo make install` 
 But one more thing you have to remember is that package dependencies . If you are installing a package means those will obtained automatically ,if not 
`sudo apt-get install -f` will do the job .

In the case of No internet connection , you have to collect all of them and thats a risky job , my opinion .

So if you want to install a package manually then you have to take care of the compilation tools nothing but build essential and dependencies of that package .

The above explanation applicable for any source packages .

But if you got builded packages directly i mean .DEB files then simply you can install them with

```
sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
```

and here also if dependencies issue may raise and you can take care of them with `sudo apt-get install -f`

If you got that package as a script(.sh) or binary file (.bin )  , the you can install with

```
chmod +x filenmae.sh
./filename.sh
```

for binary

```
chmod +x filename.bin
./filename.bin
```

Comment: If the program being compiled is in the repositories, sometimes the dependencies can be satisfied with `sudo apt-get build-dep package`; or if not, the readme included with the downloaded source code will detail the necessary dependencies.

Comment: Great!
I wasn't aware of build-essential !! I have been thinking that we can do it without anything like that(or something like that is inbuilt)...Thanks! I'll try some package without internet today :)