# Area drawing - Huion Tablet

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I've tried everything here on ask ubuntu and found good solutions for tablets drawing of HUION brand. However I have a problem that I believe has not been resolved:

I have the H420 HUION tablet and put it in ubuntu 12:04 LTS it works normal but the area is drawing on the screen is equivalent to a portion of it, say. (starting from the left top edge), and the same occurs with useful drawing area on the tablet itself.

In my case, my monitor is 1368x768 and it seems that the drawing area is only 346 pixels wide by 192 pixels high (values ​​only for you to understand better what happens)

I installed the drivers WizardPen, calibrated and managed to resolve the drawing area on the monitor, but the tablet functional area remains small (the area of the drawing tablet is too small, the pen works up to a point and discards the rest of the area)

I would like to help.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Huion Driver (kind of a beta version, but I gather it is slated to be included in the kernel, if it has not already), in the Digimend project, at

https://github.com/DIGImend/huion-driver

Works like a charm, with my H610.

Comment: P.S. If it works, keep the sources at hand... half the time something in X got updated, I had to recompile and re/install the driver.

Answer (score 1):

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, 64-bit version, and I was able to get a Huion 420 drawing tablet to work by downloading and using terminal to install the digimend drivers found here: https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases/download/v6/digimend-kernel-drivers-6.tar.gz.

I was having the same symptom of screen area of the tablet being too small. This issue was resolved by using terminal to install the digimend driver v6. For more info on how to use Ubuntu terminal to install a file ending in tar.gz read this: https://askubuntu.com/a/191391/482912

UPDATE: The symptom of the Huion's drawing area being too small on the screen being came back again after the last software update, probably because the kernel was upgraded. To resolve the issue I uninstalled the digimend drivers and instead installed an experimental set of digimend drivers that supposedly will continue to work after software updates. The experimental digimend drivers can be downloaded here: https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers/releases/download/v6/digimend-dkms_6_all.deb

For more information on how to install a file ending in ".deb" in Ubuntu terminal go here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/159114

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the 4 topic **X.org configuration** of this web site
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/digimend/index.php?title=Tablet_setup_with_WizardPen or do:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-wizardpen.conf
```

and paste before **Driver "wizardpen"**

```
   Option      "TopX"       "1506"
   Option      "TopY"       "2705"
   Option      "BottomX"    "31225"
   Option      "BottomY"    "30892"
```

i hope this resolve.

Answer (score 0):

Good news. Huion now offers beta drivers for ubuntu now.

Note that You click on the area/screen box instead of dragging it, which is a little confusing.
And you have to restart the machine after installation.
Other than that they worked great and I was able to adjust the screen area without issue.

https://www.huion.com/download/