# How Find a Linux Kernel Supported Wireless Card?

Tags: wireless

Background: I have used Ubuntu 12.04 LTS for more than one year. I have tried several times to install Driver on RTL8192 because it does not work, but without success.

Qustion: How can I find a linux-kernel supported wireless card suitable to Thinkpad SL410k.

Comment: Please explain _card_. PCMCIA, PCIe or can you live with a working USB adapter too? Did you read [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/246236/compile-and-install-rtl8192cu-driver) for some possible directions?

Answer (score 0):

go to [Realtek 8191SE](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=226&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

this will give you a download for your linux driver,then search install wireless card

[Install directions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.