# I can't run slic3r

Tags: software-installation

I just installed slic3r on my Linux computer. for some reason it doesn't start without typing `./slic3r.pl` in the terminal (all the other commands included from the tutorial [here](https://github.com/alexrj/Slic3r/wiki/Running-Slic3r-from-git-on-GNU-Linux)) what should I do so I can run it from the start? I have already tried this[tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/685225/cant-figure-out-how-to-get-slic3r-to-run) but I don't understand so much from it.

I am totally new to Linux so it would be great if someone could link me a tutorial about how to actually see the smart things.

Answer (score 0):

By "run it from the start" I guess you mean the Unity launcher, the `dash`.

The best way is to create a `.desktop` launcher, first open a text editor, for example

```
 gedit
```

Now copy this in to the file

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=slic3r.desktop
Exec=./slic3r.pl
Icon=/path/to/your/icon
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Now save this as `slic3r.desktop` in your home directory and open a terminal and make it executable with

```
chmod +x ~/slic3r.desktop
```

Now double clicking this icon will run your program, to get it to appear in the `dash` like a normal application, move it to `.local/share/applications`

```
mv ~/slic3r.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

You can now search for `slic3r` in the dash, to add an icon change `/path/to/your/icon` for the path of the icon you would like.

Applications you build your self (or script programs) don't get an entry of there own in the `dash`, you can apply this to any program to create a launcher for it.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! If this is the answer you were looking for, please click the check mark on the left to say thanks and allow others to easily find the correct answer.

Comment: i created a file in my home directory but when i start it it just shows a error and closes right after... i typed chmod +x ~/slic3r.desktop in the terminal like you said

Comment: @el97 - What is the error?

Comment: "There was an error starting the program."

Comment: Open a terminal and drag the .desktop file you made on to it and press enter, what is the error?

Comment: Did you set an Icon??? The path in the example would be invalid, add an icon path or remopve the3 line for now.

Comment: nope i didnt set a icon, i did a copy of the example without the icon part and the slic3r.desktop just dispersed all of the sudden. i searched for the applications map and i didnt find slic3r.desktop in it. what should i do now?

Comment: Try the revised desktop file, if not we will try another way.

Comment: eeh.. what do you mean with the revised desktop file? if you mean the desktop file i had for de begining it didnt work. it just loaded and stoped after a minute or so.

Comment: I just edited the answer, with a longer desktop file, try it.

Comment: "The launcher "slic3r .desktop" has not been marked as trustworthy. If you do not know the source of this file so it can be unsafe to restart it."  it was in Swedish from the beginning but i translated it with google

Comment: Did you set the permissions??? `chmod +x ~/slic3r.desktop` You must set executable permissions

Comment: yea i open the terminal and typed "chmod +x ~/slic3r.desktop" in the terminal

Comment: That code assumes you made this file in your /home folder, did you?

Comment: yea i did it in the home folder