# How do I install modern packages in Ubuntu "the right way" ?

Tags: 14.04, apt

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.3 and I'm wondering how to install a modern version of GPA (Gnu Privacy Assistant). The one present in the Ubuntu repositories is really old.

There are some modern packages on Launchpad, however I don't understand how to install the current stable release which is only available for 15.10 and not for 14.04.3

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gpa

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Nobody can help ?

Comment: If you want newer packages you should upgrade your distribution. 14.04 is for stability, not bleeding edge. This won't work as it is for a newer distro, you not only need to install this but update ALL its dependancies to the latest versions, this includes things like `gtk` and in my opinion is not worth the hours it would take to build and the hours it would take to fix the system afterwards. You want to try yourself? Please see this on building from source http://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz

Comment: Mark, thank you for this answer. I've installed 15.10 and the packages in it's repo's are quite new. (stable ones)

Answer (score -2):

1. You will need all packages follow these steps.

First [you need add  repository.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine) , What ever Git, launchpad, Debian. etc

2. `grap` mean by what application you need ?. 
   Grap mean below ddrescue is grap
   What you want from launchpad.
   ex. `sudo apt-get install dd rescue-gui`. 
   and 
   Just grape the name and add into

   sudo apt-get install --download-app-name/name

Comment: Again you present code that won't work `grape`? Not to mention this is not how to install a package, the OP asked about a certain program they want to install. -1 This does not answer the question.

Comment: `grape` mean by what application you need ?. Grap mean you get from launchpad. ex. sudo apt-get install dd resucue

Comment: grape is not a command in Ubuntu, it does not mean anything, the correct command ` grep` and it says nothing about applications, it is a text search utility for finding lines of text. Even though you edited this you still spelt `grep` wrong, it now says `grap` in one instance and `grape` in another. `grap` is some thing else altogether http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/grap.1.html nothing to do with package management, alos what is this `--download-app-name/name` that is not how to install, this is a terrible answer, full of simple spelling mistakes and misinformation