# Package installation for Ubuntu servers

Tags: software-installation

I want to install these packages:

```
linux-image-4.4.0-45-powerpc64-emb
linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic-lpae
linux-image-4.4.0-45-powerpc64-smp
linux-image-4.4.0-45-powerpc-e500mc
linux-image-4.4.0-45-powerpc-smp
```

Found `linux_4.4.0.orig.tar.gz` needs to be downloaded for installing these package. But I don't have an option to install these package after unzipping the `linux_4.4.0.orig.tar.gz` folder.

Someone please advise how I can install above said packages with the `linux_4.4.0.orig.tar.gz` gzip.

Comment: Please look at [this](http://packaging.ubuntu.com/html/packaging-new-software.html) for several options.

Comment: Not an expert but after `untarring` the file look at the `README` file in it and it will guide you, but you will some example let me see if I can find one. I suggest it be done in a virtual device first. From the `README` file its not as simple as `./configure, make, make install`.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use sudo to unpack the archive. Type this in a terminal:

tar -xzf archive.tar.gz

Or you can just double-click on the archive from Nautilus (the file manager) to see what's inside. No need for command line until now.

If this archive contains something to install in the system, then sudo would be useful at one point or another. Very often, such an archive contains software that must be compiled and then installed. Typically, what you then do is as follows:

tar -xzf archive-name.tar.gz
cd archive-name
./configure
make
sudo make install

As you see, only the step actually installing the program requires superuser rights; everything else happens just in your home directory, which you own. Please do not type blindly the instructions above; first, read any documents called "README" or "INSTALLATION" that you will find in the archive.

The source website is :

[how to use sudo command to install .tar.gz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz)

Comment: I dont see anything for installing the package, i cloud see only below said folders after untar & unzip /home/arun/linux-4.4# ls
arch   COPYING  Documentation  fs       ipc      kernel       Makefile  README          scripts   tools
block  CREDITS  drivers        include  Kbuild   lib          mm        REPORTING-BUGS  security  usr
certs  crypto   firmware       init     Kconfig  MAINTAINERS  net       samples         sound     virt