# Compiling PHP from source (an old version) will delete or corrupt my current PHP7? What is the proper way to install both + switch between them?

Tags: apache2, php, compiling, make

I have PHP  7.1 on my Ubuntu machine.

I need to work on a project that uses `php5 5.3.3-7+squeeze17` (yes... a 10 year old code).

I have found the source of this package: https://launchpad.net/debian/+source/php5/5.3.3-7+squeeze17

If I install `php5_5.3.3.orig.tar.gz` following using any of these methods:

- https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Compiling_PHP_from_source
- [how to use sudo command to install .tar.gz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/191390/how-to-use-sudo-command-to-install-tar-gz)

Will this corrupt my current PHP 7.1 and prevent it from working? (- might this change the settings via Apache2 on `install make`?)

What is the proper way to install this version, so I will be able to switch between both versions?

Answer (score 0):

All security concerns left aside I stumbled upon a great tool which might help you a lot with building and managing multiple php versions in parallel:

[phpbrew](https://phpbrew.github.io/phpbrew/) does a great job with easing the job of configuring php source to your needs and compiling it:

```
curl -L -O https://github.com/phpbrew/phpbrew/raw/master/phpbrew
chmod +x phpbrew && sudo mv phpbrew /usr/local/bin/phpbrew
phpbrew init
echo '[[ -e ~/.phpbrew/bashrc ]] && source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc' >> .bashrc
source ~/.phpbrew/bashrc
phpbrew update
phpbrew install --old 5.3.29 +default +mysql +pdo +apxs2
```

Installation is done to your $HOME directory and you can set a default php version (i.e. `/usr/bin/php`)

```
phpbrew switch 7.2
```

and override your currently used/active php version by setting it temporarily

```
phpbrew use 5.3.29
```

Comment: Ohh wow! I'll try this later on today! :)

Comment: So? Have you been successful?